# Click function, Window.location

Tags: php, html, window.location

currently, I am trying to set the URL of my website base on what the user click. The website is coding in html and php and this is the code I am trying to use to set the Url. However it seems that windows.location doesn't recognize php code. is there any other way to do this?

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){                         
    $("#HELP").click(function(){
   window.location='hotels.php?Category=<?php $cat ?>&Pic=<?php $img ?>';
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: where is echo in the statement

Comment: @Bindrid: That server-side code is wrapped in `<?php ?>` tags appropriately.  Aside from missing the `echo`, there's no reason why this approach shouldn't emit values to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){                             

  $("#HELP").click(function(){
    var url = 'hotels.php?Category=<?=$cat?>&Pic=<?=$img?>';
    window.location= url;
     });
  });
</script>
```

**What change:**
**Echo** php veriables in url

But its not a good practice to use php code in client side you can create global veriables in **java script**.

Or if your requirement is like that than you can also use a hidden value for url in **html** and than get value in your **jQuery** code as like that:

```
<input type="hidden" id="url" value="<?=hotels.php?Category=<?=$cat?>&Pic=<?=$img?>" name="url">

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#HELP").click(function(){ 
var url = $('#url').val(); 
window.location= url; 
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Why is it not good practice to emit server-side values into client-side code?  This is a fairly straightforward and commonly applied use case.

Comment: Yes it is. Depend on your requirement if you aware about the object oriented java script than you can easily handle it otherwise no bad impact will occur if u want to use this @david

Comment: @david I have also post another solution

Comment: This seems to overcomplicate what is essentially a single line of code.

Comment: Yes it just a solution my friend  @david

Comment: OHHH thanks guys ^^ i been trying to figure it out for hours ^^ i will try out the hidden value ^^

Comment: @Melvin: you are welcome, now mark as accepted the best answer this will help to other who also facing this issue.

Comment: @devpro is it possible for the #HELP in this code to also accept a php code?? $(document).ready(function(){ $("#HELP").click(function(){

Comment: Currently my code is a loop and if i use #HELP, it only allows user to click on the first item and not the rest

Comment: allright, now you can use a javascript function and pass a id, can you share the code or create a separate question? @Melvin

Comment: @Melvin: as per stack overflow policy, please do not use answer section for question... put this in your question or create a new question... i am looking this.

Comment: oops sorry did not realize let me create a new question

Comment: yes sure, share your question also, and chose the best answer here and mark as accepted other wise this question always open..

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to `echo` the variables to the output:

```
window.location='hotels.php?Category=<?php echo $cat ?>&Pic=<?php echo $img ?>';
```

Variables *by themselves* don't emit anything to the page.  They simply represent a value.

Comment: OHHH thanks guys ^^ i been trying to figure it out for hours ^^